# "No data received" error when I have a mysql query in while loop

Tags: php

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    include_once("connect_to_mysql.php");

    $max=300;
    while($max--)
    {
        sleep(1);
        doMyThings();
    }
?>
```

it is supposed to repeat a mysql query 300 times with gap of 1 second between each. But the problem is after a minute or so in the browser i get this message:  No Data Received. Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.

Comment: @DainisAbols: How so? $max would eventually be equal to 0, and the loop will break.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Sorry, true. I though it would go in minuses too ;)

Comment: Actually @DainisAbols, this method of looping is 50% more efficient than starting with $max = 0 and going up to 300 (because you use two statements to check and increment, where here you only need one statement to both decrement and check).

Comment: What do you think browser must return? And how long web server must wait answer from your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following: Your code will at least (without considering the amount of time needed by `doMyThings()`) last 300 seconds. Most PHP environments set the default script running time to about 60 secs, the script stops and nothing is printed out.

Next thing is (if script execution time is set high enough to allow long running scripts), the script has to run until its finished (that is, ~300 secs) and after that, data is written onto the output stream. Until there, you won't see any output.

To circumvent those two problems, see this code:

```
<?php
    // If allowed, unlimited script execution time
    set_time_limit(0);

    // End output buffering
    ob_end_flush(); 

    include_once("connect_to_mysql.php");

    $max=300;

    // End output buffering IE and Safari Workaround
    // They will only display the webpage if it's completely loaded or
    // at least 5000 bytes have been "printed".
    for($i=0;$i<5000;$i++)
    {
        echo ' ';
    }       

    while($max > 0)
    {
        sleep(1);
        doMyThings();
        $max--;

        // Manual output buffering
        ob_flush();
        flush();            
    }
?>
```

Maybe this post is also of interest to you: [Outputting exec() ping result progressively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807607/outputting-exec-ping-result-progressively/10814087#10814087)

Answer (score 2):

The browser will not wait a whole 5 minutes for you to complete your queries.

You need to find a different solution. Consider executing the PHP script in CLI.

Comment: In most cases Browsers won't wait 5 minutes :) But you can apply some neat tricks to have them to ;)

Comment: @GeneSys: I can shoot you in the face, doesn't mean I should :P

Comment: for example is not proof ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a timeout executing 300 times doMyThings();
You can try with `set_time_limit(0);`

> Set the number of seconds a script is allowed to run. If this is reached, the script returns a fatal error. The default limit is 30 seconds or, if it exists, the max_execution_time value defined in the php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute long time php code on server side, you need change  max_execution_time directive in php.ini. But browser will not wait how long as you want so you need use async technology like AJAX